# Python ndb.Model Required Attribute is None

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have an `ndb.Model` class `ProjRoute` which has an attribute `date` which I declare in the model as follows:

```
class ProjRoute(ndb.Model):
  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required=True)
  priceValue = ndb.FloatProperty(default=None)
  attachement = ndb.KeyProperty()
  src = PriceFilterProperty()
  dest = PriceFilterProperty()
  # Required qty
  reqQty = ndb.FloatProperty()
  ldQty = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  unldQty = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  amountDue = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  scale1 = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  scale2 = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  toll1 = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  toll2 = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  port_permit = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  port_scale = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  maintenance = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  other = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  fuel = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  gratuity = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  driver_allow = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  adriver_allow = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
  driver_bonus = ndb.FloatProperty(default=0)
```

I am pretty sure that I do set a date value when creating a new `ProjRoute` instance, and in fact I don’t face any problems when calling the `put()` function.

However, when I try to read the instance I get an error because the `date` attribute in null.

```
BadValueError: Entity has uninitialized properties: date
```

This error also doesn’t appear every time I try to read an instance, it’s arbitrary.

I think that something must be wrong with the GAE itself, but anyone knows how to fix it or know of a work-around?

By the way, when I log any `ProjRoute` instance I find that attributes are stored as `GenereicProperty` not `FloatProperty` and `KeyProperty` like I had declared in the model. I think this might be related.

In case you care to look at it, here is the code where I create a new instance:

```
trsPrices = map(float, self.readAll('trs-price'))
for src, dest, price in zip(self.readAll('trs-price-src'), self.readAll('trs-price-dest'), trsPrices):
    route = ProjRoute(id=newPrice.src+"-"+newPrice.dest, parent=routeParent)
    route.attachement = newPrice.attachement
    route.src, route.dest = newPrice.src, newPrice.dest
    route.date = trsSrv.sdate
    route.priceValue = None
    toSave.append(route)

# ... Some irrelevent code
ndb.put_multi(toSave)
```

Also FYI, I have tried using `route.put()` instead of `ndb.put_multi` but the problem remained.

Comment: Have you looked at the datastore developer console to see if your dates are set ? I must admit it is quite weird as it is impossible to save an Entity with a missing "required" property... Haven't you saved entities in datastore before setting the property as required ?

Comment: Hi, yes I have checked and it is often None (like I said sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn’t)

Comment: That is already the answer for the "non-working" part. The question is now, how do this entities got there in the first place. Was the "required" field always present in your model ? Does it still happen that None values get put with your current code ? Have you ever edited your entities through the web interface ? Do you have another model in another module with the same name that could generate some conflicts ?

Comment: Yes the required field was always present. And not I have never edited them using the web interface. And no I don’t have any other classes with the same now (good idea though)

Comment: Do the GenericProperties appear for every entity of your model or only some of them ? GenericProperties are usually found for Expando models, which is not the case here. It really looks for me as if you have two methods in different modules maybe updating the same entities with different restrictions.

Comment: It is quite weird... Have you tried to log your "toSave" list before saving it, just to see if your dates are present ? I must admit there is something here I'm missing...

Comment: Yes, I have tried logging the instance before saving it and everything is always right at this point. Keep giving me ideas though we might eventually find something. :D

Comment: I think you should take the view that it's not GAE but your code.  If this really was a GAE problem then lots of people will be having the issue. Have you checked that trsSrv.sdate is in fact a date object ?

Comment: Yes I have and it is correct.

Comment: Oh and I meant to say in the earlier comment is it a "DateTIme" Object not just date.  Have you validated/logged the values of the property and type for that key before calling for put ?  And have you done this for a put, that has resulted in the error of that record on retrieval?  (I have been using appengine and the datastore since 2008 and used date objects heavily, and never encountered any problems).